# Python regular expressions ending at "

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to take a long sting and extract all the urls it contains.

```
page.findall(r"http://.+")
```

is what I have, but that doesn't result in what I want. The urls are all wrapped in double quotes, so how can I tell regular expressions to stop matching when it reaches a "?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are very complex url-parsing regexes out there, but if you want to stop at a `"`, just use `[^\"]+` for the url part.

Or switch to a single-quoted string and remove the `\`.

Also, if you have `https` mixed in, it will break, so you might want to just go with

```
page.findall(r'"(http[^"]+)"')
```

But now we're getting into url-parsing regexes.

Comment: (I think) the raw string won't work with the `\"`, so if not following the single quote advice, drop the `r` string prefix.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I don't think `\"` breaks it... it's just unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a non greedy expression here instead of using `[^\"]+`. That way your regex would be `r'"http://.+?"'`. The question mark after the plus makes it so that it finds to the first encounter of a double quote.

Comment: That's what I came up with after what I posted in the question, but now I end up with a list of all the urls, but they all end with a ". How can I get rid of that using regex?

Comment: How is `[^\"]+` greedy?  It will never match any quotes, let alone gather as many as possible.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you please explain why non greedy is better than the character class?

Comment: `[\"]+` is not the greedy part I was talking about, I was referring to  `.+`. IMHO `.+?` looks a lot cleaner than `[\"]+`, and it also avoids the discussion about escaping the double quotes or not.

Comment: @user1624005 To capture just the url, you should put the part inside the quotes in parentheses, like `r'"(http://.+?)"'` or `'"(http://[^"]+)"'`